# Does anyone know how to emulate the search box on www.foodnetwork.com?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Does anyone know how to create a search field, similar to what is on the www.foodnetwork.com website? It contains a definition list to help the user select what area to search. If anyone knows of a demo site where someone might be building this, I would appreciate it. It's a very cool feature.

Comment: It's pretty simply done. Some HTML/CSS and javascript to change a hidden element based on the selection of the menu. Just use firebug (Firefox) or Eleemnt Inspector (chrome) and look through the tree at the elements/styles being used.

Answer (score 1):

It's just an autocomplete textboox. There are lots of tutorials around the Web if you Google it. (Random pick from the Google results: [Auto-complete Control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/jsactb.aspx).) jQuery UI 1.8 also includes an [autocomplete feature](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete) that pretty much handles it for you.